# Imprimir registros con un dato en comun y otros diferentes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Esta es mi situación:
Tengo un **dataframe** que pose varios registros de servicios a clientes pero muchas veces las personas que pasan estos registros comenten errores al digitar los nombres o los apellidos (puede ser mas campos). Necesito encontrar los registros que compartan el id_cliente pero que tengan diferentes los campos nombre y apellidos

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"id_cliente":[1234,1234,1234,2345,2345,2345],"nombre":["pepe","pepel","pepe","ramon","ramoni","ramon"],"apellido":["castillo","cardona","castillo","Ramirez","Ramirez","Rasquillas"]})
```

No quiero usar ciclos for pero lo unico que se me ocurre es utilizar **duplicated**

```
df[df.duplicated("id_cliente",keep=False)]
```

Pero esto de lejos satisface mi necesidad. Código completo:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"id_cliente":[1234,1234,1234,2345,2345,2345],"nombre":["pepe","pepel","pepe","ramon","ramoni","ramon"],"apellido":["castillo","cardona","castillo","Ramirez","Ramirez","Rasquillas"]})
df[df.duplicated("id_cliente",keep=False)]
```

Agradezco sugerencias.

Comment: Buen día, no entiendo bien como es que tienes pensado que funcione, ¿La salida esperada sería que para cada `id` muestre todas las combinaciones con otras columnas? Porque si esperas que solo devuelva por ejemplo la fila `1234 pepel cardona` el programa ¿Cómo podría adivinar que `pepel` está mal y `pepe` bien?

Comment: Buenas noches, lo que quiero es que en la salida salga los registros que comparten id_cliente pero que tengan nombres y apellidos diferentes. en un **dataframe** con cientos de registros, quiero que me saque los registros que se duplican y con el agregado que si esos registros duplicados en id_cliente tengan nombres y apellidos diferentes. Es necesario hacer esas correcciones para algunas métricas.

Comment: Y claro, tienes razon en que no sabría decir que pepel esta mal, pero por eso necesito esos registros duplicados en id_cliente pero que tengas nombres o apellidos diferentes para preguntar cual es el correcto y hacer correcciones antes de subir. Es enrreado,

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es, en tu `dataframe` de ejemplo tienes 6 filas y únicamente 2 de ellas coinciden todos las columnas que necesitas. El `dataframe` resultante de tu ejemplo sería de 5 filas? Es decir,¿Todas las combinaciones diferentes? Yo creo que si agregas un ejemplo de como debería verse el resultado para tu ejemplo sería más claro y te podríamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

La validación de datos siempre es un proceso complicado que requiere de cierto trabajo manual, en la respuesta intento reducir el trabajo manual para que puedas aplicar el código casi directamente a tus datos

**Nota:** Agregué algunos datos al `dataframe` y puse algunos nombres con mayúsculas y otros con minúsculas para intentar hacer un ejemplo más cercano a la realidad.

Con el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    id_cliente  nombre  apellido
0   1234        Pepe    Castillo
1   1234        Pepel   cardona
2   1234        pepe    castillo
3   2345        Ramon   Ramirez
4   2345        ramoni  Ramirez
5   2345        ramon   Rasquillas
6   1234        pepel   cardona
7   1234        pepe    cardona
8   1234        pepel   cardona
9   1234        pepe    cardona
10  1234        pepel   cardona
```

Vamos a obtener un `dataframe` auxiliar que nos permitirá ver las diferentes combinaciones entre `id_cliente`, `nombre` y `apellido`

Para eso utilizamos [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) junto con [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html) o [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html), ambas opciones funcionarían igual y devuelven el mismo resultado, yo voy a utilizar `size` porque tiene menos letras jajaja.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['id_cliente', 'nombre', 'apellido'], as_index = False).size()
```

Al imprimir `df1` obtenemos el siguiente `dataframe` donde `size` va a mostrar el número de ocurrencias (Que en realidad no es relevante pero únicamente queremos ver todas las posibles combinaciones y tal vez te sirva en un futuro):

```
    id_cliente  nombre  apellido    size
0   1234        Pepe    Castillo    1
1   1234        Pepel   cardona     1
2   1234        pepe    cardona     2
3   1234        pepe    castillo    1
4   1234        pepel   cardona     3
5   2345        Ramon   Ramirez     1
6   2345        ramon   Rasquillas  1
7   2345        ramoni  Ramirez     1
```

**Nota:** Hasta aquí se resolvería tu pregunta inicial, pero pensando en el proceso siguiente te dejo una propuesta.

Ahora viene el proceso manual, de este `dataframe` tenemos que empezar a validar los datos e indicar las filas que tienen los datos correctos, primero vamos a crear una nueva columna `válido` y marcar todas las filas como `False`

```
df1['válido'] = False
```

**Nota:** De hecho podrías hacer este proceso desde el inicio si tuvieras una lista con los datos correctos, sin tener que revisar las combinaciones como se mostro en la primera parte de la respuesta.

Luego creamos 3 listas para indicar los datos válidos (Podrías cualquier iterable o hacer uno por uno)

```
id_cliente = [1234, 2345]
nombre = ['Pepe', 'Ramon']
apellido = ['Castillo', 'Ramirez']


for i, n, a in zip(id_cliente, nombre, apellido):
    df1.loc[(df1['id_cliente'] == i) & (df1['nombre'] == n) & (df1['apellido'] == a), 'válido'] = True

print(df1)
```

Esto devuelve el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    id_cliente  nombre  apellido    size    válido
0   1234        Pepe    Castillo    1       True
1   1234        Pepel   cardona     1       False
2   1234        pepe    cardona     2       False
3   1234        pepe    castillo    1       False
4   1234        pepel   cardona     3       False
5   2345        Ramon   Ramirez     1       True
6   2345        ramon   Rasquillas  1       False
7   2345        ramoni  Ramirez     1       False
```

Por último utilizamos este `dataframe` auxiliar para sobre escribir los datos incorrectos del `dataframe` original con la ayuda de la columna `válido`:

```
def sobreescribir(row):
    if row['válido'] == True:
        df.loc[df['id_cliente'] == row['id_cliente']] = row[:-2].values

df1.apply(sobreescribir, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Al imprimir el `dataframe` original (`df`): obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
    id_cliente  nombre  apellido
0   1234        Pepe    Castillo
1   1234        Pepe    Castillo
2   1234        Pepe    Castillo
3   2345        Ramon   Ramirez
4   2345        Ramon   Ramirez
5   2345        Ramon   Ramirez
6   1234        Pepe    Castillo
7   1234        Pepe    Castillo
8   1234        Pepe    Castillo
9   1234        Pepe    Castillo
10  1234        Pepe    Castillo
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id_cliente":[1234,1234,1234,2345,2345,2345,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234],
                   "nombre":["Pepe","Pepel","pepe","Ramon","ramoni","ramon","pepel","pepe","pepel","pepe","pepel"],
                   "apellido":["Castillo","cardona","castillo","Ramirez","Ramirez","Rasquillas","cardona","cardona", "cardona","cardona", "cardona"]})

df1 = df.groupby(['id_cliente', 'nombre', 'apellido'], as_index = False).size()
df1['válido'] = False

# Creamos las listas con datos válidos
id_cliente = [1234, 2345]
nombre = ['Pepe', 'Ramon']
apellido = ['Castillo', 'Ramirez']

# Marcamos con True las filas del dataframe auxiliar donde los datos son válidos
for i, n, a in zip(id_cliente, nombre, apellido):
    df1.loc[(df1['id_cliente'] == i) & (df1['nombre'] == n) & (df1['apellido'] == a), 'válido'] = True

# Función para sobre escribir el dataframe original
def sobreescribir(row):
    if row['válido'] == True:
        # Nota: de la fila del dataframe auxiliar solo necesitamos las primeras 3 filas, por eso el límite superior es -2
        df.loc[df['id_cliente'] == row['id_cliente']] = row[:-2].values

# Utilizamos el dataframe auxiliar para sobre escribir el dataframe original
df1.apply(sobreescribir, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien, lo que quieres es imprimir las filas de datos de `df` que contengan el mismo valor, en tu caso `1234`, para la variable `"id_cliente"`.

En tal caso, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id_cliente":[1234,1234,1234,2345,2345,2345],"nombre":["pepe","pepel","pepe","ramon","ramoni","ramon"],"apellido":["castillo","cardona","castillo","Ramirez","Ramirez","Rasquillas"]})

mi_lista = df.loc[df['id_cliente'] == 1234]

print(mi_lista)
```

Comment: Hola, no como tal y me disculpo si no hice  bien la pregunta. Lo que necesito es coger esos registros donde se repite id_cliente pero nombres y apellidos sean diferentes. Esto es importante para algunos informes donde miran estas inconsistencias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero voy a cambiar ligeramente tus datos de entrada para aclarar tu pregunta, ya que en tus datos de entrada **todos** los `id_cliente` cumplen la condición que pedías (que estén duplicados pero sus nombres y apellidos sean diferentes), lo que hace confusa la pregunta.

Sea el dataframe de entrada el siguiente:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(
   {"id_cliente":[1234,1234,1234,2345,2345,2345,3456,3456],
    "nombre":["pepe","pepel","pepe","ramon","ramoni","ramon","juan","juan" ],
    "apellido":["castillo","cardona","castillo","Ramirez","Ramirez","Rasquillas","nadie","nadie"]}
)
```

```
   id_cliente  nombre    apellido
0        1234    pepe    castillo
1        1234   pepel     cardona
2        1234    pepe    castillo
3        2345   ramon     Ramirez
4        2345  ramoni     Ramirez
5        2345   ramon  Rasquillas
6        3456    juan       nadie
7        3456    juan       nadie
```

En este caso las dos últimas filas tienen el mismo `id_cliente`, pero también el mismo nombre y apellidos, por lo que estarían "bien" y no deben aparecer en el resultado.

Dado el dataframe anterior, entiendo que lo que pides no es más que una lista con los ids 1234 y 2345.

### Posible solución

Intentando obtenerlo en una sola línea de código (aunque rompo la línea para mejor legibilidad), lo siguiente hace lo que se busca:

```
mal = df.groupby("id_cliente")\
        .apply(lambda d: len((d.nombre+d.apellido).unique()))\
        .where(lambda x: x>1).dropna().index
```

La variable `mal` será un iterable que contiene `1234`, `2345`. Puedes imprimirlo como lista:

```
print(list(mal))
```

```
[1234, 2345]
```

### Cómo funciona

Como ves, se comienza por un `df.groupby("id_cliente")`, lo que agrupa todos los id_cliente iguales, creando un "mini-dataframe" para cada id_cliente. Seguidamente se aplica una función lambda a cada uno de esos mini-dataframes mediante `.apply(lambda d: ...)`. Lo que ocurre aquí es que cada vez que se llame a esa lambda, el parámetro `d` será un "mini-dataframe" sacado de `df`, en el que el índice será `id_cliente` y todos los valores del índice serán iguales. En este caso se llamará por tanto tres veces a la lambda, una cuando el índice sea 1234, otra cuando sea 2345 y otra cuando sea 3456

Lo que hace nuestra lambda es concatenar las columnas `nombre` y `apellido` para después aplicar `.unique()` al resultado. `unique()` elimina repetidos, y devuelve una lista que solo tiene elementos diferentes.

Por ejemplo, para el id 1234 el resultado de `unique()` sería la lista `["pepecastillo", "pepelcardona"]`, para el id 2345 sería la lista `["ramonRamirez", "ramoniRamirez", "ramonRasquillas"]` y para el id 3456 sería la lista `["juannadie"]`.

Finalmente con `len()` tomamos la longitud de esas listas y eso será lo que retorne la lambda. Como ves, lo que retorna es *cuántos nombres diferentes aparecen para ese id*. Por tanto el resultado de `.apply()` sería una serie con tres filas. El índice de la serie serían los id_clientes, y los valores de cada fila el resultado de la lambda, es decir, cuántos nombres diferentes aparecen para cada id. En nuestro ejemplo sería esto:

```
id_cliente
1234    2
2345    3
3456    1
```

A este resultado se le aplica `.where(lambda x: x>1)`, lo que pone un NaN en las filas que no cumplan esa condición (tener valor mayor de 1), o copia el valor que hubiera en las que sí lo cumplen. El resultado sería en este caso:

```
id_cliente
1234    2.0
2345    3.0
3456    NaN
```

Finalmente `.dropna()` elimina las filas con NaN, que son las que estaban "bien" porque la cantidad de nombre+apellido diferentes era 1, y para terminar `.index` se queda con el índice del dataframe resultante, que contendrá ya solamente los id_clientes que estaban "mal".

### Bonus

Una vez tienes la lista de ids `mal`, puedes obtener los registros que corresponden a esos ids desde el dataframe original, por ejemplo así:

```
df[df.id_cliente.isin(mal)]
```

```
   id_cliente  nombre    apellido
0        1234    pepe    castillo
1        1234   pepel     cardona
2        1234    pepe    castillo
3        2345   ramon     Ramirez
4        2345  ramoni     Ramirez
5        2345   ramon  Rasquillas
```

O mejor aún, haz que `id_cliente` sea el índice del dataframe y usa `mal` para acceder a los índices deseados:

```
df = df.set_index("id_cliente")
df.loc[mal]
```

```
            nombre    apellido
id_cliente                    
1234          pepe    castillo
1234         pepel     cardona
1234          pepe    castillo
2345         ramon     Ramirez
2345        ramoni     Ramirez
2345         ramon  Rasquillas
```